# Trigger event on closing of Window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

Hi I have to load an url in window.open, that url save some cookie in my browser, I want to access it after that window.open is closed. I couldn`t find a way to do it. I have tried these codes.

```
 var windowStatus = window.open(returnURL, "Login", "type=fullWindow,toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,fullscreen");
 windowStatus.addEventListener("beforeunload", (event) =>{
      let cookieVaal = this.cookieService.get('QSTID');
      sessionStorage.setItem('QSTID', cookieVaal);
    })
```

This is also not working, Kindly suggest me something. Thanks in advance..

Comment: What part of your code is not working? Does the event fire? Are you failing to retrieve the cookie? Are you failing to store it?

Answer (score 2):

```
var new_window = window.open('url')
new_window.onbeforeunload = function(){ my code }
```

Comment: Looks like it will be worked. Thanks, Friend.

Comment: To simple and direct!!! I do recommend !

Answer (score 0):

The OP may be bumping into the ["Same Origin"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) restriction in setting the cookie and accessing it.  Here is some JavaScript that I ran on my personal webserver:

```
    var url = "http://localhost/exp/alpha.php";
    var strWindowFeatures = "menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";
    var new_window = window.open(url,'Alpha',strWindowFeatures);
    new_window.document.cookie = "name=rose";

    // okay:
    //new_window.onbeforeunload = function(){ alert(document.cookie)};

    // better; brings up dialog box to confirm leaving page
    new_window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (e) => {
      alert(document.cookie);

     // Cancel the event
  e.preventDefault();
    // Chrome requires returnValue to be set
 e.returnValue = true;
    });
```

The script only runs as long as the indicated url is on the same web server as the executing JavaScript code.

More about [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload).